# Creating a Laravel attribute (accessor) on model but unable to access model properties

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Here's my code:

```
    protected function expires(): Attribute
    {

        if ($this->started_at) {
            $expiry = $this->started_at->addDays(20);
        }

        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn () => $expiry ?? null 
        );
    }
```

Running this code gives me an `ErrorException` with the message `Undefined property: Models\Job::$started_at`

I have found that I can work around this error by accessing the property through `$this->attributes['started_at']` as follows:

```
    protected function expires(): Attribute
    {

        if ($this->attributes['started_at']) {
            $expiry = Carbon::parse($this->attributes['started_at'])->addDays(20);
        }

        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn () => $expiry ?? null 
        );
    }
```

However, this code feels a little inefficient because I'm manually using Carbon to parse the property back into a Carbon object. But if I do a `dd($this->started_at)` right before the if statement, it's already been cast to a Carbon object by Laravel and I'd really just like to use this object to make my code as clean as in the first example above.

I'd like to know the reason why `$this->started_at` is apparently available as a Carbon object in this context but somehow not usable (an undefined property) in the way I'm using it, and also I would like to know if there is another way to go about achieving my goal?

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct syntax for Laravel 8: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor, it's different than what you have, which is the syntax for Laravel 9: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 1):

you can add custom attributes with

```
public function getExpireAttribute()
{
    if ($this->started_at) {
        $this->started_at->addDays(20);
    }

    return $this->started_at;
}
```

now you can access expire attribute like other, with

```
$model->expire
```

to make Eloquent casts dates to Carbon for you, add attribute to casts:

```
protected $casts = [
   'started_at' => 'datetime',
];
```